# Rounded progress bar in Progressbar - Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, progress, rounded-corners

I'm trying to make a progress bar rounded, the background works fine, but the progress bar (the orange one) does not appear rounded, any solution for that?

this is the image of my application:

[image]

and this is what I want:

[image]

This is the code of my progressbar:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="13dip" />
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="#ff747674"
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:endColor="#ff9d9e9d"
            android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="13dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#f3c30b"
                android:centerColor="#efa200"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#ce7428"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Comment: using ClipDrawable will cut your rounded Drawable so thats why you cannt see rounded right side, use a custom Drawable reacring for level changes

Comment: can you hive me an example?

Comment: class D extends Drawable { ... and override onLevelChange calling invalidateSelf inside so any call to setLevel invalidates the Drawable

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<clip>..</clip>` with `<scale android:scaleWidth="100%">..</scale>`.